# OpenVPN behind router

Tags: vpn, openvpn, ubuntu-18.04

Hi I am trying to setup VPN on ubuntu behind the router. I have a router with IP 192.168.1.1 and a running openvpn server 192.168.1.2 on ubuntu 18.04 following the setup from https://github.com/angristan/openvpn-install/. However, I cannot connect to the vpn using the .ovpn file on a client. I have tried the following.

1. changed `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1` in /etc/sysctl.conf
2. set up static ip pool

   - /etc/openvpn/ccd/user1: `ifconfig-push 10.8.0.2 255.255.255.0`
   - /etc/openvpn/ipp.txt: `user1,10.8.0.2`
3. port forwarding using

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.1.1 -p udp --dport 32400 -j DNAT --to-dest 10.8.0.2:32400
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p udp -d 10.8.0.2 --dport 32400 -j ACCEPT
```

Is that because I have to assign the static ip 10.8.0.2 using .ovpn file? Or I have missed something? Here is my server configuration. Thanks!

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
keepalive 10 120
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
dh none
ecdh-curve prime256v1
tls-crypt tls-crypt.key 0
crl-verify crl.pem
ca ca.crt
cert xxxx.crt
key xxxx.key
auth SHA256
cipher AES-128-GCM
ncp-ciphers AES-128-GCM
tls-server
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd
status /var/log/openvpn/status.log
verb 3
```

Comment: You don't port forward on the server but your router, so that `your_public_ip:32400` leads to `192.168.1.2:1194`

Comment: The `10.0.8.x` IPs are for communicating within the "virtual network" after the connection is established. With `mode server` (implied by the `server` directive) IPs have to be pushed.